# Set attribute with for loop but only gets the last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to write a code to spawn buttons automatically, each buttons contain an image(photo).

What I imagine is to build an array of specific numbers to match images filename, then use for loop to put these numbers in to source attribute. What I got is the last image for all buttons, but console log does out put each number and I'd try forEach loop also with the same result.

Please guide me through whatever problems you see in the codes below.

HTML:

```
<div class="warp">
    <main class="houseFlat">
        <div>
            <h1>平面圖</h1>
            <img src="images/flat.svg" alt="Not found">
        </div>
        
    </main>

    <aside class="rooms">
        <h1 class="font-color">房間配備</h1>
        <div class="info font-color">
            WIFI 機上盒 螢幕 書桌 椅子 床鋪 衣櫥 冷氣
            A室7坪，B室6坪，C室3.5坪，D室8.5坪，E室3坪
        </div>
        
        <h1 class="font-color">地圖</h1>
        <div class="map">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3642.9838607597326!2d120.54495771537542!3d24.066872882528724!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3469395bcc5c6775%3A0x9125cf5bce6a2584!2zNTAw5b2w5YyW5Y6_5b2w5YyW5biC5LuL5aO95Y2X6LevNjnlt7c05byENeiZnw!5e0!3m2!1szh-TW!2stw!4v1598363699365!5m2!1szh-TW!2stw" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>

<div class="img_preview">
</div>

<div id="dialog">
        <div class="room room_a">
            <div class="popup">A
                <button class="close">X</button>
                <div class="photos">
                    <!--image slider here-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<div class="forFooter"></div>
<script src="jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/effects.js"></script>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //導入頁淡入特效

$(function(){//移植header
    $(".forHeader").load("header.html");
});

$(function(){//移植footer
    $(".forFooter").load("footer.html");
});

   /*spawn buttons*/
    var num= 25;
    var source= "images/house_JS";

    for(var i=1; i<=num; i++){
        $(".img_preview").append("<button class='btn'><a><img></a></button>");
    } 
    
    var setnum= [], j, split; 
    for(j=1; j<=num; j++){ //generate 01,02,03....25
        split = ('0'+j).slice(-2);
        setnum.push(split);
        console.log(setnum);
    }

    setnum.forEach((nums)=>{ //get numbers and use them as image source
        console.log(nums);
        $("button > a > img").attr('src', source + nums +'.jpg');
    });
```

});

Comment: Did you know that `$(document).ready(func...` and `$(func...)` are basically the same thing? The sooner you drop jQuery, the better. There's little point of bearing the burden of its bad API anymore.

Comment: ...and BTW, there are now padding functions, so instead of `('0'+j).slice(-2);`, you can do `String(j).padStart(2, "0");`, which is a bit clearer

Comment: Well, I'm newbie in coding. $(func... was in the html file when I typed it, and  move it to js file for more clearer look. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button > a > img").attr('src', source + nums +'.jpg');
```

This is affecting ALL `button > a > img` tags every time you run it.
Additionally, all 3 of your loops are doing a different thing that should be done in the same loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/5foj43mp/3/

```
var num= 25;
var source= "images/house_JS";

for(var i=1; i<=num; i++){
  $(".img_preview").append("<button class='btn'><a><img src='"+source + ('0'+i).slice(-2) +".jpg'></a></button>");
}
```

Comment: Can I ask one more question. Why the loop do things differently when  $("button > a > img") means look through button and <a> tag to img tag?

Comment: ```$("button > a > img")``` is targeting all the element and applying change to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num= 25;
var source= "images/house_JS"; //no need of this variable

let i=1;
while(i<=num){
  let index = ('0' + i).slice(-2);
  $(".img_preview").append(`<button class='btn'><img src="images/house_JS${index}.jpg"></a></button>`)
  i++;
}
```

Comment: `<img src="${source + index + '.jpg'}">` Seems like you'd be better off keeping the static string parts out of the computed string interpolation. `<img src="images/house_JS${index}.jpg">` Or even: `<img src="images/${source}${index}.jpg">` if they really wanted that variable.

Comment: The while loop works as well, thanks for the instruction.